# Sending multiple emails and not marked as spam using Domino

Tags: spam, ibm, ibm-domino

I would like to send mass emails to about 2,000 addresses.

However, if I send them at once, then antivirus engines mark them as spam suspects

Is there a functionality or feature that we can provide so that the mail server (IBM Domino) processes such emails a batch at a time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the problem while sending from an internal application to your own Domino server.  In that case,  I would check the AntiVirus SW manual on how to whitelist certain senders.